# clang-format align consecutive ctors

Tags: c++, clang-format

I am trying to get clang-format to align the delete assignment on special constructors and assignment operators.

It currently looks like this when formatting:

```
Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
Foo(Foo&&)      = delete;
Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = delete;
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Foo(const Foo&)            = delete;
Foo(Foo&&)                 = delete;
Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
Foo& operator=(Foo&&)      = delete;
```

I feel like `AlignConsecutiveAssignments` should solve this but it does not.

Help is greatly appreciated!